# How to pass arguments to the printf C function in assembler?

Tags: assembly, x86, printf, nasm, x87

I've added a similar question several times, but unfortunately I still haven't found the solution to my problem. I have a program that calculates the roots of quadratic equations, they count well, but I can't display two results at the same time. Below I add the way I try to do it, but this way only one result is displayed. And the second one displays 0. Can anyone say what I should do to display these 2 results.
I know that many things in the code can be done better and simpler, I also got a lot of advice on this topic, but unfortunately my lecturer does not accept other solutions than the ones he showed himself. I would be very grateful for any help.

```
 [bits 32]

        call getaddr

   format db "x1 = %lf", 0xA
          db "x2 = %lf", 0xA, 0
   offset equ $ - format

   a      dq 1.0 ;
   b      dq -11.0
   c      dq 28.0
   minusfour  dq -4.0

   getaddr:

        finit
        mov eax, [esp]
        lea eax, [eax+offset] ; eax = a
        mov edx, [esp]
        lea edx, [edx+offset+8] ; edx = b
        mov ecx, [esp]
        lea ecx, [ecx+offset+16] ; ecx = c
        mov esi, [esp]
        lea esi, [esi+offset+24] ; edi = minusfour

    /* Here's the code where I do stack operations to access the numbers needed to calculate the 
       roots */

        ;x1
          fsubp st1; st: -b-delta
          fld qword[eax]; st: -delta-b, 2a
          fdivp st1; st: (-delta-b)/2a => solution1
          lea eax, [esp+4]
          fstp qword[eax]
          call[ebx+3*4] ;print function
          add esp, 2*4

       ;x2
          faddp st1; st: -b+delta
          fld qword[eax]; st: delta-b, 2a
          fdivp st1 ; (delta-b)/2a => solution2
          lea eax, [esp+12]
          fstp qword[eax]
          call[ebx+3*4] ;print function
          add esp, 3*4

          push 0
          call[ebx+0*4]
```

Comment: You only ever store one `double` on the stack (above the point to `format` that the first `call` pushed in your shellcode-like hack, stepping on whatever data any earlier code might have had there.)  And that matches the format string because it's 0-terminated before the `x2 = %lf` part.

Comment: Also the code in `;x2` presumably crashes when it tries to use the `printf` return value in EAX as a pointer.  You haven't shown what table of function pointers `ebx` is pointing to when this code runs, but I'm assuming that's actual printf, not some other wrapper you haven't shown...  If so, you can adapt examples / compiler output that call `printf` to create the same state of values on the stack with a format string with 2 `%f` conversions.  Use a debugger to single-step your code and examine the stack at the point of the call.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you, I got a little closer to solving the problem because I already know how to get to the second result and display it at `x2 =` (previously the results were only displayed at `x1 =`) but I don't understand one more thing. As you write the error is the first time the print function is called, but I have no idea how else I could use it. That is, what to do to call it while not crashing the code at `;x2`. I know and I'm stupid that I'm probably asking about the basics, but the lecturer doesn't really explain it well, and the solutions found on the internet don't help

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for all the hints, also in my previous questions, I finally managed to solve the problem